# Compile Error Message in SSRS

Tags: sql, visual-studio, t-sql, reporting-services

I am working on an expression which will change the cell background color based on the values of two different columns. One column being a percentage and the other a number representing file size (gb)

Note: Column names are Free_Space and Free_Space__ (ssrs doesnt like % sign apparently)

Here is the expression

```
=Switch((Fields!Free_Space__.Value >= 20), "Lime", (Fields!Free_Space.Value > 50) AND (Fields!Free_Space__ > 10), "Lime", (Fields!Free_Space.Value > 50) AND (Fields!Free_Space__ < 10), "Orange", (Fields!Free_Space.Value < 50) AND (Fields!Free_Space__ > 10), "Orange",  (Fields!Free_Space.Value < 50) AND (Fields!Free_Space__ < 10), "Red")
```

For some reason when I try previewing the report in SSRS I am getting the following error:

> Compiler Error Message: BC30452: Operator '>' is not defined

Can anyone see what is wrong with my expression? I truly do not understand where I am going wrong.

Thanks all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the.Value properties from !Free_Space__.  Without them, it believes that you are trying to compare objects (is this object greater than 10? impossible to tell).

Try this instead:

```
=Switch((Fields!Free_Space__.Value >= 20), "Lime", _
        (Fields!Free_Space.Value > 50) AND (Fields!Free_Space__.Value > 10), "Lime", _
        (Fields!Free_Space.Value > 50) AND (Fields!Free_Space__.Value < 10), "Orange", _
        (Fields!Free_Space.Value < 50) AND (Fields!Free_Space__.Value > 10), "Orange", _
        (Fields!Free_Space.Value < 50) AND (Fields!Free_Space__.Value < 10), "Red")
```

Comment: Wow, I can't believe I was starring at this for half an hour and didn't notice something so simple. Thanks @tgolisch fro the fresh eyes!

Comment: Happens to me all of the time.  Glad I could help.

Comment: do you see anything else wrong with the format of my expression? A new error was raised as follows.. Warning 1 [rsRuntimeErrorInExpression] The BackgroundColor expression for the text box ‘Free_Space_InAutoSubtotal1’ contains an error: Input string was not in a correct format.

Comment: 1) is this (above) the formula for textbox 'Free_Space_inAutoSubtotal1'?  2) what is the output type?  (string, not number, right?)  3) have you changed the query at all?  That can mess up the formulas.  If so, check your list of available data fields and match-up/fix the names.

Comment: when i do this condition with one variale it works. But when i use Free_Space and Free_Space__ it does not

Comment: Sorry, I nearly forgot that this is a light form of VBA. When I wrote it to be on multiple lines, it needs line continuation characters "_". Otherwise, it will see the end of each line as the end of each statement and it chokes. I updated my answer to include line continuation chars.

Comment: that raised error: "Identifier Expected". Thanks for the tip anyways!

Comment: It seems almost as if there's a limitation which does not allow conditions to contain values from different columns...

Comment: I don't know if this is the problem, but you did forget the logical condition where (Fields!Free_Space.Value = 50) AND (Fields!Free_Space__.Value = 10)